# Can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this mismatch error VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, type-mismatch

I have this code which is causing a mismatch error and I can't figure out why I had it working sort of before with the mismatch error and in an attempt to fix it I can't get it back to working. The values in the merge sheet are all numeric. Basically what I was trying to do was when a value is entered into a cell there would be a `VLookup` would be executed to input a value into the adjacent cell and once I get this working, more cells in the same row. If any of you are itching to fix something just let me know!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim LooupValue As String
    Dim sfx As Long
    Set KeyCells = Columns(1)
    LooupValue = ActiveCell.Value
    sfx = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, Worksheets("Merge").Range("D:BD"), 2, False)

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = sfx

    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @Marcucciboy2, @MathieuGuindon, and @BigBen for their successful help, I have done some more research and posted what solved my issue down below.

Comment: Just a thought, not related to your error - you don't need to use `Range(Target.Address)` - `Target` is already a range so you can just refer to it directly.

Comment: @BigBen ha, missed that - good eye!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out what the last problem was... The lookup column was, for some reason from the previous document editor, formatted as text. The reason why only some lookup values were working was because even after I formatted the entire column to numbers, the said values were reformatted as numbers only after I had edited the cell. I wasn't going to edit every single cell so I did some research and found out how to refresh an entire column's format.

I refreshed the column by doing the following:

1. Select the entire column
2. Format the column as necessary
3. Go to the Data ribbon and select 'Text-to-Columns'
4. Ensure Delimited is selected, click Next
5. Uncheck all the Delimiters, click Next, then Finish

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Dim sfx As Long
> sfx = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, Worksheets("Merge").Range("D:BD"), 2, False)
> ```

If the `vlookup` yields `xlErrNA` i.e. `#N/A`, then VBA can't coerce its result into a `Long`, and you get exactly that: a *type mismatch* error - because `xlErrNA` is an `Error` value, which can't be implicitly converted to a `String`, a `Long`, or anything. The only type that can contain this data, is a `Variant`.

```
Dim result As Variant
result = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, Worksheets("Merge").Range("D:BD"), 2, False)

Dim sfx As Long
If Not IsError(result) Then 
    sfx = CLng(result)
Else
    'lookup yielded no match
End If
```

Also, it looks like this is off-by-one:

> ```
> LooupValue = ActiveCell.Value
> ```

The `ActiveCell` likely isn't the same cell as `Target`, which is the cell that was modified. You probably need this instead:

```
LookupValue = Target.Value
```

I'd also recommend making unqualified `Range` (same with `Rows`, `Colomns`, `Names`, and `Cells`) calls explicitly qualified - because that exact same code behaves differently depending on where it's written in. By qualifying them with `Me`, you're making your code more explicit. Code that *says what it does, and does what it says*, is always better code.

`Worksheets("Merge")` is a smell: if the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, give it a *code name* (i.e. set its `(Name)` property) and use that identifier directly:

```
result = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, MergeSheet.Range("D:BD"), 2, False)
```

If the sheet only exists at run-time (e.g. it's in a workbook that was opened by the macro), then you should have a reference to that workbook near where you opened that file, e.g. `Set book = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)` - use that reference to qualify the `Worksheets` member call, instead of implicitly referring to `ActiveWorkbook`.

The lookup range `D:DB` is excessive when you're only looking for the value in column `E`. If that hard-coded `2` is there to stay, I'd make the lookup range be `D:E`.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with my 'VLookup' because some values, not all, still turn up the #N/A Error after I changed both 'LoupValue' and 'sfx' to 'Variant' types from my original code snippet.

Comment: @MikeBeal should `LookupValue` not be assigned to `Target.Value` (the cell that was modified) rather than `ActiveCell.Value` (the current-active cell, which is likely one adjacent to it)?

Comment: Yeah that's partly what helped, but the same couple values are showing up with the same #N/A error.

Comment: @MikeBeal then the values are not in your lookup area. Are they?

Comment: I've checked manually that they are indeed in the lookup area

Comment: Short of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51049544/1188513), there's nothing more for answerers to chew on at the moment.

Comment: when you specify the ranges for intersect, offset, and vlookup, is only one of them on the second sheet "Merge" ?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 only the one in the 'VLookup' is on the sheet "Merge"

Comment: Interestingly when I named the worksheet it threw a 438 run-time error "Object doesn't support this property or method I assume it'd be like this: 'Name ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Merge") As MergeSheet'

Comment: huh? no, you name a worksheet by selecting the sheet in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R) and then setting its `(Name)` property in the *Properties* toolwindow (F4). The `Name` instruction is for renaming files.

Comment: Oh yeah, haha, woops. Ok so the 438 run-time errors are not there anymore as they shouldn't have been there to begin with. I still have some values that are '#N/A'. My code looks like [this](http://rextester.com/MYYLB54301) now.  EDIT: Sorry, for the late response had some plans that got in the way.

Comment: `#N/A` means the lookup is failing, and that's something your code needs to handle. The `IsError` function can be used for validating whether the lookup result is an `Error` or a valid value, as shown above.

Comment: Right, but the thing is, the values that it's looking up are there, I've double checked myself. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: One thing I did find is that it seems to be working only for repeated values

Answer (score 2):

I would also nest the value setting within the "If" that checks for intersection; otherwise, every time you change the worksheet it does an unnecessary vlookup in the background.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).value = Application.VLookup(Target.value, Worksheets("Merge").Range("D:BD"), 2, False)
    End If
End Sub
```